# toc vector in GUI Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, vector, tableofcontents

I have created a GUI, using GUIDE. I have added pushbuttons which perform a task. The start button, plots a graph and plays a wavefile that I have assigned to it. in the start button I have added as well a 'tic'.

on the other side of the GUI is have another button, the save button. The function of that button is to save to a vector the exact time that I push the button. The code that I have used saves only the last instance, while I want to be able to see all of the elements of that vector.

```
  handles.counter.push(handles.count + 1)
  handles.sfront(size(handles.counter)) = toc
```

Is there a way to save all of the instances to the sfront vector?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store your handles every time before the end of callback function.

Use [GUIDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html):

```
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Comment: I just forgot to update the structure! 
all I was missing was one command line "guidata(hObject, handles);"

Answer (score 0):

To add a new element to the end of a vector use:

```
handles.sfront(end+1) = toc;
```

Then call guidata(hObject,handles) to store the updated version of handles.

I can't recreate your entire GUI here, but here's an example of storing multiple toc outputs in a vector.  Takes about 10 seconds to run:

```
tic
tocList = [];
for i = 1:5
    tocList(end+1) = toc;
    pause(2)
end
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but still doesn't do what I want.
I would like to see 

   sfront = [3.351 4.84 9.84 etc];

With the code I have I see

   sfront = [0 0 9.84 etc];

so basically it saves only the last toc, while the rest of the vector is zero.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want it to record toc every time the button is pushed? Are you using guidata to update handles in this callback?

Comment: Yes, I want it to record toc everytime I push the button.
I thought though that handles update own its own.
What do you mean exaclty?

Comment: Ok, I added an example to my answer that might help. You can adapt this to your GUI. Make sure you're calling guidata(hObject,handles) to store the updated version of sfront.

Comment: function Front_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)                         
    % hObject    handle to Front (see GCBO)                                  
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB                                
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)            
    handles.counter.push(handles.count + 1);               
    handles.sfront(size(handles.counter)) = toc             

so I should update the handles.something using guidata? doesn't that work only for obj?

Comment: You need to call guidata(hObject,handles) (that exact code) to store handles in the GUI.